# Is there is any event that fire when the Custom report type is created?

Tags: apex

My requirement is that whenever the Custom report Type is created I want to do DML operation on Custom object. That will store the information related to that Custom report Type into the custom Object.

Thanks,
Sandesh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Reports and Report Types both do not support triggers, workflows, or processes. You'd have to approach this by way of a scheduled job that periodically queries for new metadata and then performs the operations you want.